# Highlight fundamental types differently than other keywords in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight C++ fundamental types like `int`, `bool`, `double`, etc., differently than other keywords, like `for`, `if`, `class`, etc. in Visual Studio text editor. What is the easiest way to do it?

Native Visual Studio 2013/2015 functionality is preferred. If not, a free extension is ok. If not, I can use VisualAssistX or Resharper++.

What I was able to find:

- [User-defined keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8.aspx). Does not allow to distinguish between C++ keywords.
- [Creating a Classifier Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885492%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). Seems like it can do what I want, as [pointed out in this article](http://lolengine.net/blog/2012/11/27/visual-studio-syntax-highlighting), but I found no ready solution with this approach, and I don't want to write code on my own for such a basic task.
- [Highlighterr](http://highlighterr.codeplex.com/). Looks outdated, and I would like to avoid exploiting IntelliSense. I have it disabled for (huge) projects at work since it consumes vast amount of space and I just don't have enough on my SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a bit more than what you want, but you could use this extension called [Viasfora](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/19609469-380e-4fcf-bcde-e31caeb658b2) for this. First of all, Viasfora is an extension that gives you things like rainbow braces (which are very useful), keyword highlighting, and more.

Anyways, if you have Viasfora, go to **Tools->Options->Viasfora->Languages->C++**. You'll see two sections, *Control Flow* and *Visibility*. By default *Control Flow* has keywords like if, else, while, for, etc. and *Visibility* has words like public private, protected, etc. Well you could change the *Visibility* section to include any of the keyword you wanted and you could change the color in the "Fonts and Colors" section in Options.

If you don't want the keyword highlighting for *Control Flow*, you could just erase all of the keywords in that section. Also, if you don't want any of the other Viasfora features, you can try to disable them in the Viasfora options.

By the way, if you do want to erase all of the keywords for the *Control Flow* section, you might get an error saying "property value is not valid". To get past this, just click on the little square button on the right ( looks like [...]) and erase all of the text from there. I don't know why this is, but it works. Hey, you might even like how it does the control flow highlighting so you may decide to keep it.

**Edit: I noticed that you can't actually leave Control Flow blank because it fills in the defaults after you apply it. You can, however, use some character and that works fine. I just used a space character (' '). That's a weird hack, but it's not too bad.**

I do urge to at least try out the rainbow braces. I find it extremely useful when looking for matching braces. No more counting braces! Also, you can customize the color of each brace and choose how many different colors are used.

Comment: Wow, seems like it does what I want! Thanks! One question: "Viasfora flow control keyword" items are rendered italics. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @Mikhail Unfortunately, I don't think you can disable the italics. I wish you could. It is an open source project, so you might bee able to easily change that from the code. You might even be able to see how it does it's syntax highlighting and make your own extension. I would love to do that, but I don't know anything about VS extensions. I hope I can find the time to learn it in the future though. It would be cool to make an extension where you can highlight any words you want.

Comment: FYI, enabling/disabling italics for flow control keywords is now supported in Viasfora.

Answer (score -1):

Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Fonts and Colors

But you should understand that int, double and other standard data types are also keywords, so their appearance is defined by Display item "Keyword"

Comment: I think OP understands that very well and he's asking for distinction, therefore your answer is not helpful.